# Add missing spaces before and after HTML tags

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I'm trying to figure out the best method for adding missing spaces before and after HTML tags.

For example

```
some<b>text</b>
```

Needs to updated to

```
some <b>text</b>
```

Using

```
[\w][<]
```

With the replace of `$1`

Results in

```
somb>text</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go `([\w])([<])`on your regex and `$1 $2`on your replacement text

Answer (score 0):

Try these two find and replacements:

**Find:**

```
(\w+)(<\w+>)
```

**Replace:**

```
$1 $2
```

And then this one:

**Find:**

```
(<\\\w+>)(\w+)
```

**Replace:**

```
$1 $2
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this "<(?=\w+>)"

with " <"

it catches any opening tag and adds a space before it. It works perfectly fine in notepad++ too.